# Copying and Syncing Files on the Same Computer

Tags: sync, file-transfer

I have a slightly unusual situation. I've got some files in a folder (as you do), and I'd like to make a copy of them to another locations (easy so far). However, I'd like this secondary copy to automatically update and synchronise with the first. I already do this between two of my computers using syncthing, but I can't work out how to do it on the one computer!

Comment: You will require file synchronization software to do this, the best place to ask is [here](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Ah, I had not heard of that part of SE! Hopefully an admin can migrate my question for me (as I already have an answer). Thanks though!

Comment: Ah, my mistake, sorry! Spent quite a while searching Google and SE, but I didn't come across that one -- apologies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may look as if I am peddling software but [DSynchronize](http://dimio.altervista.org/eng/) looks like it may work.

Comment: Installed that. Nice little piece of software and works exactly as I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is using a [directory junction](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194.aspx?tduid=%28b787abda1ad249a30d8307b64e67808d%29%28256380%29%282459594%29%28XdSn0e3h3.k-nx6nSCtoqCPehWizl80.CQ%29%28%29&f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) a viable solution?

Comment: I saw these on other SE answers, but I really wanted a copy not a directory junction. Thanks for the suggestion though -- I should have perhaps mentioned that in the question!

Comment: Okay, if you don't mind me asking, why do you want two copies instead of a junction? 'm sure it's a valid reason but it's taking up twice as much disk space as it needs to.

Comment: Yeah, no problem asking! It's only a few hundred megabytes, so that's not really a problem for me. I've got a folder with about 12 folders in it -- I want to upload three folders to Google Drive, but not the whole lot. So I wan to copy over those three folders (individually) to the Google Drive folder.

Comment: Copy (similar to Google Drive) has a nice feature -- as lots do -- that you can just make a shortcut to the file and then Copy uploads the files, not the shortcut. I want it on Google Drive to then be able to use offline on my tablet. But I don't want to sync straight to my tablet, as then the tablet and computer have to be on at the same time to sync -- with Google Drive, it goes onto the cloud, then download at my convenience.

Comment: If it was me, I would just make junctions of the three folders I wanted to sync, but your solution works too so if that's what you're comfortable with then that's fine :)

Comment: Yeah, I think I could have probably junctioned it -- I do that sort of things sometimes, but these days I'm more a fan of a more basic approach -- less thought involved, haha! =P